# why doesn't clang++ compile the following code?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
}
```

g++ file.cc -std=c++0x

works just fine.

However, I need to use clang++ for some reason.

When I try

clang++ file.cc -std=c++0x

I get a bunch of errors:

```
In file included from file.cc:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4.4/type_traits:50:
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/type_traits:230:41: error: expected ')'
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
                                        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/type_traits:230:28: note: to match this '('
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
                           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/type_traits:230:12: error: redefinition of 'is_function<type-parameter-0-0 (type-parameter-0-1, ...)>'
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/type_traits:227:12: note: previous definition is here
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/type_traits:233:29: error: type qualifier is not allowed on this function
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...) const>
....
```

clang++ --version gives:

```
clang version 2.8 (branches/release_28)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Any ideas how to fix that? (-std=c++11 doesn't work, not recognized.)

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading Clang.

Comment: @chris not my server... any way to work around with the current version? though I will ask to upgrade it, just may take some time.

Comment: You have to add a return statement to your main

Comment: @kloop Try `clang++ file.cc -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++`. Also, `<type_traits>` was first introduced as part of TR1, so you may find what you're looking for in `<tr1/type_traits>`.

Comment: @Praetorian same errors...

Comment: @Bruno I should, but this is a test file, and not necessary in this case. the errors originate in some other problem.

Comment: @Bruno, According to every ISO standard of C++, you do not.

Comment: You might try std=c++11 or ditch the compiler

Comment: @Dieter: error: invalid value 'c++11' in '-std=c++11'

Comment: @kloop Your clang version is just too old. See my earlier comment about TR1, that might be your only option other than upgrading the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang 2.8 does not support C++11 features, you need to upgrade your compiler to use them.

Comment: So how come I don't get an error with -std=c++0x? If I try something else than that, I do get an error (unsupported language or something of that sort.)

Comment: @kloop Don't use `type_traits`. Rewrite the functions you need by hand. They're not that complex. That's the only thing you can do with an outdated compiler.

Comment: @kloop I guess the added the flag for compatibility, but as you can see [here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), clang supported basically no C++11 before at least Clang2.9. As long as your compiler does not have a `-c++11` flag, you have to expect major problems.

Comment: @Malloc thanks. I guess given everybody's advice, the best thing to do is upgrade clang.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph the issue really comes up with #include <string>, which includes type_traits. that was just an MWE.

Comment: @kloop C++0x was an identifier used prior to the final publication of C++11 - they had originally intended to finalize before 2010. So your compiler may support features *proposed* for ISO C++, but not necessarily all, and some features may have been dropped or modified in the final standard.

Comment: @kloop It seems that your library and compiler are from different eras of C++. There's really not much to do in such a situation.